# Styling a WebView XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, webview

I am currently displaying HTML content in a webview using

```
WebView.NavigateToString("<html><body>" + Content.content + "</body></html>");
```

This produces the content as expected however there is currently no styling. How would I go about adding styling for HTML elements like lists and paragraphs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to give your content some styling you will need to provide the appropriate css file to it.

You can do this by using the "ms-appx-web" protocol when adding the css file.

```
WebView.NavigateToString("<html>
                          <head>
                          <link rel=\"stylesheet\" 
                                href=\"ms-appx-web:///Views/web/web.css\" 
                                type=\"text/css\" 
                                media=\"screen\" />
                          </head> 
                          <body>" + Content.content + "</body></html>");
```

You can look at the original blog post describing how to do it. [[Windows 8] Insert a local CSS/JS file in the HTML of a Webview](http://blog.thomaslebrun.net/2013/04/windows-8-insert-a-local-cssjs-file-in-the-html-of-a-webview/#.V1QOb49OKiM)

Good Luck.